# repetition of words: how to merge

Tags: repetition

> You understand that a good brand strategy and a strong advertisement
>   strategy are the bases of a succesful advertising campaign.

How would one avoid the repetition of strategy?

> ...a strong brand and advertisement strategy..

This seems to imply you need a strong brand (not strategy) and any (not a strong) advertisement strategy

Would this be correct nevertheless?

Comment: Anything wrong with "strong brand and advertisement strategies?"

Comment: Can this not also be interpreted as needing a strong brand and multiple (not strong) strategies? But it is allready way more clear, so I might use that.

Comment: It could be, but that would be a really odd interpretation of it. Even your original example would be unlikely to be misinterpreted in the way you said, but this just makes it a bit less ambiguous. If you're *really* concerned, the repetition would probably be necessary to make it absolutely clear that both strategies should be strong, but I don't think it's needed in this case. (edit: to point out *why* mine is less ambiguous, consider the sentence "We need X" where X is an item from the list: "We need strong brand" makes no sense, so it's clearly meant to be a list of strong strategies).

Comment: @JohnClifford That doesn't necessarily mean the same.

Comment: The word *strategy* **seems** to be repeated -- nothing is really repeated, though. Note that "brand strategy" and "advertisement strategy" are significant noun phrases with established definitions -- they are "terms," not incidental word pairs.

Comment: I'm sure there's a Greek term which pictures the orator thumping the table as an important word is repeated. The repetition works well here.

Comment: Got it: *"analepsis repetition of a word or phrase for emphasis;"*

Comment: Why do you feel the need to take a clear statement and contort it into a confusing one?

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence:

> You understand that a good brand strategy and a strong advertisement
>   strategy are the bases of a succesful advertising campaign.

One possible rewrite that avoids repeating the word "strategy:

> You understand that strong strategies around branding and
>   advertisement are the bases of a successful advertising campaign.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strategy as an [umbrella word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbrella_term) to cover both branding and advertising as gerunds. Gerunds can take adjectives too!

So;

> You understand that good brand and strong advertisement strategies are the basis of a successful advertising campaign.

; dropping the indefinite article as the the two singular objects are combined into a plural object.